# MySQL not using indexes; using filesort

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, filesort

MySQL appears to be not using indexes and is using filesort on the following query:

```
  SELECT `tweets`.* 
    FROM `tweets` 
   WHERE (`tweets`.contest_id = 159) 
ORDER BY tweet_id ASC, tweeted_at DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

I have indexes on contest_id, tweet_id and tweeted_at

When I execute `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`, Extra returns "Using where; using filesort". How can I improve my query?

Comment: Do you have a single index covering `contest_id, tweet_id, tweeted_at`? or are they multiple single column indexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you mix `ASC` and `DESC` sorting, MySQL cannot use indexes to optimize the `GROUP BY` statement.

Also, using multiple keys to sort will result in it not being able to optimize the query with indexes.

From the docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use
>   indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it still uses indexes to find
>   the rows that match the WHERE clause.
>   These cases include the following:
>
> You use ORDER BY on different keys:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key1, key2;
>
> ...
>
> You mix ASC and
>   DESC:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1
>   DESC, key_part2 ASC;

If the two columns you are ordering on are not part of the same key, then you are doing both of the above things.